# Firestore - Object not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an object of this structure:

```
{
  assignments: []
  faqs_url: "oi"
  id: "pW68CiGZJMZJzyY1GExz"
  name: "oi"
  notes: {
    file: {
      extension: "pdf", 
      type: "base64"
    }
    name: "o"
    url: "http://192.168.1.111:3000/notes/o.pdf"
  paper: "P1"
  past_topicals: []
  video_lectures: []
}
```

Now when I update the object by calling `set(obj, {merge: true});`

where

```
obj1 = {
  assignments: []
  faqs_url: "oi"
  id: "pW68CiGZJMZJzyY1GExz"
  name: "oi"
  notes: {
    name: "chnged name"
    url: "http://192.168.1.111:3000/notes/o.pdf"
  paper: "P1"
  past_topicals: []
  video_lectures: []
}
```

What it does is, it replaces the `notes` object and removes the `file` key from the object as it is not present in the updated object.

My question is, doesn't `merge: true;` work for nested objects?

Is there any way I can make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Merging/updating doesn't work the way you describe.  You will have to read the contents of the document, modify the value of the field in memory, and write it back to the document.